# Undefined symbols for architecture armv7 while integrating speechkit of nuance dragon mobile

Tags: ios, speech-recognition

I integrating my app with speechkit of naunce dragon mobile when run i am below error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_kCFStreamPropertySSLPeerCertificates", referenced from:
      l469 in SpeechKit(libSpeechKit.a-armv7-master.o)
      l642 in SpeechKit(libSpeechKit.a-armv7-master.o)
      l643 in SpeechKit(libSpeechKit.a-armv7-master.o)
  "_kCFStreamSSLValidatesCertificateChain", referenced from:
      l469 in SpeechKit(libSpeechKit.a-armv7-master.o)
  "_kCFStreamSSLAllowsAnyRoot", referenced from:
      l469 in SpeechKit(libSpeechKit.a-armv7-master.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AVAudioPlayer", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in SpeechKit(libSpeechKit.a-armv7-master.o)
  "_kCFStreamSSLPeerName", referenced from:
      l469 in SpeechKit(libSpeechKit.a-armv7-master.o)
  "_kCFStreamSSLAllowsExpiredRoots", referenced from:
      l469 in SpeechKit(libSpeechKit.a-armv7-master.o)
  "_kCFStreamSSLAllowsExpiredCertificates", referenced from:
      l469 in SpeechKit(libSpeechKit.a-armv7-master.o)
  "_SecCertificateCopySubjectSummary", referenced from:
      l642 in SpeechKit(libSpeechKit.a-armv7-master.o)
  "_SecCertificateCopyData", referenced from:
      l643 in SpeechKit(libSpeechKit.a-armv7-master.o)
  "_kCFStreamPropertySSLSettings", referenced from:
      l469 in SpeechKit(libSpeechKit.a-armv7-master.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Please suggest me to sort out this error

Answer (score 48):

It seems you haven't added `CFNetwork.Framework`, `SystemConfiguration.Framework` and `Security.Framework` to your project. Add them in Xcode at the "libraries to link" section, and everything should be fine.

Comment: @Huey I'm a magician :) Simple: `symbols not found` is a linker error - it means that after compilation of the individual source files, the resulting object files can't be linked together in a complete executable, because there are functions missing. These functions are in the frameworks. By knowing the prefixes of the most common frameworks by heart (CoreFoundation - CF, Security - Sec etc.) it's easy to tell what it is necessary to do.

Comment: Stumbled upon this when AFNetworking cocoapod wouldn't build -- had to add Security.framework.  nice answer.

Comment: Thanks so much for explaining about the framework prefixes; always nice to learn something on top of fixing an issue. :]

Answer (score 6):

Sorry for the late reply.  I just solved this issue myself.

H2C03 is close, but it's actually CFNetwork.Framework and Security.framework that you need.

It's unfortunate the Speech Kit Basics walkthrough in the Dragon docs only shows that you need UIKit.framework, Foundation.framework, CoreGraphics.framework, AudioToolbox.framework, SystemConfiguration.framework, and SpeechKit.framework.  It's a little misleading.

If you open up the DragonMobileRecognizer sample project you can compare the frameworks it uses to yours and see what you're missing.

[image: DragonMobileRecognizer Sample Project Frameworks]