# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64 while integrating Nuance Dragon Mobile

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

I'm developing an iOS app within XCode, and attempting to integrate the Nuance mobile SDK. I've got their sample app working, and am now trying to add it to my existing app. When I do, I'm met with the errors below. I've already looked at the similar [Undefined symbols for architecture armv7 while integrating speechkit of nuance dragon mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11492600/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-armv7-while-integrating-speechkit-of-nuance-d), but following the answer (ensuring the CFNetwork and Security frameworks have been added) did not resolve my problem. As you will see the prefixes of the undefined symbols (nmsp) don't seem to match any known "core" library.

Based on the symbol names, it seems to me that XCode is missing some of the Nuance code, but I don't know what exactly. I've included the Nuance SpeechKit framework, which is the only thing I know of to add from Nuance.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_nmsp_audio_player_create", referenced from:
      l093 in SpeechKit(libSpeechKit.a-x86_64-master.o)
  "_nmsp_audio_player_delete", referenced from:
      l017 in SpeechKit(libSpeechKit.a-x86_64-master.o)
  "_nmsp_audio_player_getAudioSink", referenced from:
      l027 in SpeechKit(libSpeechKit.a-x86_64-master.o)
  "_nmsp_audio_player_start", referenced from:
      l027 in SpeechKit(libSpeechKit.a-x86_64-master.o)
  "_nmsp_audio_player_stop", referenced from:
      l038 in SpeechKit(libSpeechKit.a-x86_64-master.o)
  "_nmsp_audio_recorder_create", referenced from:
      l092 in SpeechKit(libSpeechKit.a-x86_64-master.o)
  "_nmsp_audio_recorder_delete", referenced from:
      l076 in SpeechKit(libSpeechKit.a-x86_64-master.o)
      l080 in SpeechKit(libSpeechKit.a-x86_64-master.o)
  "_nmsp_audio_recorder_reinitialize", referenced from:
      l028 in SpeechKit(libSpeechKit.a-x86_64-master.o)
  "_nmsp_audio_recorder_start", referenced from:
      l028 in SpeechKit(libSpeechKit.a-x86_64-master.o)
      l053 in SpeechKit(libSpeechKit.a-x86_64-master.o)
  "_nmsp_audio_recorder_stop", referenced from:
      l037 in SpeechKit(libSpeechKit.a-x86_64-master.o)
      l040 in SpeechKit(libSpeechKit.a-x86_64-master.o)
      l045 in SpeechKit(libSpeechKit.a-x86_64-master.o)
  "_nmsp_dr_dictation_result_create", referenced from:
      l035 in SpeechKit(libSpeechKit.a-x86_64-master.o)
  "_nmsp_dr_dictation_result_delete", referenced from:
      l035 in SpeechKit(libSpeechKit.a-x86_64-master.o)
  "_nmsp_dr_dictation_result_getSentence", referenced from:
      l035 in SpeechKit(libSpeechKit.a-x86_64-master.o)
```

Comment: The symbols cannot be resolved. Have you linked your code with the SpeechKit framework for the relevant target (x86_64, armv7, etc) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was building using an unsupported iOS version for the Speechkit lib that I had downloaded.

Answer (score 1):

On the Nuance Mobile SDK site there is a page on using SpeechKit with more information:
[Using Speech Kit](http://dragonmobile.nuancemobiledeveloper.com/public/Help/DragonMobileSDKReference_iOS/SpeechKit_Guide/Basics.html)

In particular:

The Speech Kit framework depends on some core iPhone OS frameworks that you must include as dependencies in your application so that they are available at run time. In addition to Foundation, you must add the System Configuration, Audio Toolbox, CFNetwork, AVFoundation, and Security frameworks to your Xcode project:

[image: Required dependent frameworks]